# Issues with toggling layers with mapbox.js

Tags: layers, mapbox

I am having issues with toggling map layers with mapbox.js. Using the code from [https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/] it pulls the basic mapbox base maps ex. mapbox.outdoors or mapbox.satellite as toggle layers, but the polygons on the personal map layer does not appear. I know that the map can be pulled by itself, but when I try to add it to a toggling map, the polygons do not appear. I am not sure if it is a problem with the code itself that isn't allowing my personal map to show, or if there is an issue with my mapbox map.

My github repository is https://github.com/beyeraut/mappingmv/blob/gh-pages/attempt.html

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you explain where you have added the polygons that are not showing up? Are they in Mapbox Studio, TileMill, GeoJSON, etc. Also (remember to issue a new Mapbox Access token after the problem is solved) - anyone can go in and take it as it stands. but it will be fine if you issue a new token.

Comment: The polygons were made in QGIS and pulled into mapbox classic as a GeoJSON file. And thanks for the advice about the access token!

Answer (score 3):

Your GeoJSON would be a featureLayer for your map (project) so you would need to add that separately using the loadID method. Adding it as a map would include the featureLayer by default. You can add the features using something like [loadID](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.3.0/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-featurelayer-loadid):

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .addTo(map);

// loads markers from the map mapbox.dark on Mapbox,
// if that map has markers
featureLayer.loadID('mapbox.dark');
```

Comment: Your answer is missing a word before the first period.

Comment: zoops! updated!